# NSURLConnection doesn't call delegate methods

Tags: iphone, delegates, nsurlconnection

I saw similar questions here, but I couldn't find solution to my problem.
I have a simple NSURLConnection in main thread (At least I didn't create any other threads), but my delegate methods aren't get called

```
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

and no methods called, e.g.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
}
```

`self` is also a delegate for NSXMLParser, but I think it should not be a problem, as I have this working in my other class in the same project. I checked everything 10 times already, but can't find any problem.

I've seen some hack to solve it here: http://www.depl0y.com/?p=345 but I don't like it, May be someone knows better solution? thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only reason I know is a separate thread (that is already terminated when the delegate methods are called).

Try to `NSLog(@"Is%@ main thread", ([NSThread isMainThread] ? @"" : @" NOT"));`right before the url connection  creation

Comment: I changed it to `NSLog(@"Is main thread %@", ([NSThread isMainThread] ? @"Yes" : @" NOT"));` and getting "Is main thread Yes"

Comment: so should the answer be yes or no, I am having the same issue.  none of the delegate methods are being called

Comment: @zambono, do you initiate the connection in the main thread (or manually managed background thread)?

Comment: what should i do if it NOT a main thread! i m not explicitly creating any thread!! my function which does `NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` is getting called for each new request,first request is Main thread but "not" main thread from 2nd request onwards!!!

Comment: @Yadnesh, if you initiate the URL connection in the main thread then its callbacks also arrive in the main thread. Anyway, you might initiate it in the main thread each time by using `dispatch_async`. Or you can use it in a background thread and using the synchronous call... There are also many other ways to implement it, but these 2 seem to be the easiest.

Comment: One more scenario in which this can happen; I created a connection from inside a code block that happened to take place on a separate thread :) +1

Answer (score 15):

Try running your connection on main thread:

```
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                         delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
            forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```

Answer (score 4):

The autorelease is dangerous.  The calls to the delegate are made after your function returns (asynchronously).  Are you retaining it somewhere else?

Comment: problem is not in autorelease((, I made as Eugenio Depalo suggested

Comment: The connection may and should be released right after its allocation and initiation. This is not the reason.

Comment: This is indeed a very common misstake. watch out for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `release` the `NSURLConnection` object in the `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` callback as pointed out in the Apple documentation, not elsewhere:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  // Do whatever you want here

  // Release the connection
  [connection release];
}
```

Don't release it with `autorelease`, as Lou Franco suggested.

If it is not the problem, then maybe you have to implement all the required methods in the delegate class:

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`

The delegate is retained by `NSURLConnection` so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: He didn't suggest it)), but anyway, I removed autorelease, release it in connectionDidFinishLoading, but it doesn't help(((

Comment: The connection may and should be released right after its allocation and initiation. This is not the reason.

Comment: Yes, I have all this 4 methods ((

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have missed `NSURLConnectionDelegate` in your class header file.

For example:

```
@interface yourClass : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```